# Using signal to index a model reverse M2M

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch-py

I have followed many examples and docs, but cannot get this right.

I'm trying to make my Elasticsearch index whenever I update a model. Using the 'autoindex' does not log M2M's.

1. When I change a value inside `Tag` it should update the index of all the `Items` is is in

I am using `django-elasticsearch` ([here](https://github.com/liberation/django-elasticsearch)) which is a wrapper around `elasticsearch-py`.

When I try `connect(tag_index, sender=Tag.item.through)` it cannot find tag as it hasn't been imported by models yet.

How is this correctly achieved?

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    taglevel = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def tag_index(instance, **kwargs):
    Task.instance.es.do_index()

class Item(EsIndexable, models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)

    class Elasticsearch(EsIndexable.Elasticsearch):
        serializer_class = TaskEsSerializer
        fields = ['title', 'tag']

@receiver(post_save, sender= Task)
def index_elastic(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.es.do_index()

m2m_changed.connect(tag_index, sender=Item.tag.through)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it isn't as "smart" as I thought it was. You need to refer to functions in each model

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    taglevel = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender= Tag)
@receiver(post_delete, sender= Tag)
def index_tag(instance, **kwargs):
    Item.objects.get().es.do_index()

def tag_index(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.es.do_index()

class Item(EsIndexable, models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)

    class Elasticsearch(EsIndexable.Elasticsearch):
        serializer_class = ItemEsSerializer
        fields = ['title', 'tag']

@receiver(post_save, sender= Item)
def index_elastic(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.es.do_index()
```